# Problem with my implementation of QuickSort

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm trying to sort files by their extensions (and if the extensions are the same so by the file's name) using my own implementation of quickSort.

So when I'm sorting a small group of files it works fine but when I'm using a big group, from some reason some files are disappearing from the result list. I can't find the cause for that. 
(the sorting itself works as expected... the problem is only with the missing files).
Any ideas?

```
public static ArrayList<Extention> quickSort(ArrayList<Extention> list)
{
    if (list.size() <= 1)
        return list; // Already sorted

    ArrayList<Extention> sorted = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Extention> lesser = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Extention> greater = new ArrayList<>();
    Extention pivot = list.get(list.size()-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++)
    {
        //int order = list.get(i).compareTo(pivot);
        if (list.get(i).getExtention().compareTo(pivot.getExtention()) < 0)
            lesser.add(list.get(i));
        else if (list.get(i).getExtention().compareTo(pivot.getExtention()) == 0){
            if (list.get(i).getFileName().compareTo(pivot.getFileName()) < 0){
                lesser.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        else{
            greater.add(list.get(i));}
    }

    lesser = quickSort(lesser);
    greater = quickSort(greater);

    lesser.add(pivot);
    lesser.addAll(greater);
    sorted = lesser;

    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: I assume you are doing it yourself for educational purposes? You understand that there is no other good reason to not use Collections.sort() instead?

Comment: Beyond that: such a task is **perfect** for using TDD. Meaning: write tests *before* you write production code. First sort a null list, then an empty list, then a list with one member. Then a list with two members that would need to be swapped. And so on. Dont write all your production code, without any nice tests at hand. Also note that true quicksort does **not** work by creating new sublists all the time. You do your work **in place**. Your implementation is quite wasteful about memory usage!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing an `else` in this section:

> ```
>     ...
>     else if (list.get(i).getExtention().compareTo(pivot.getExtention()) == 0){
>         if (list.get(i).getFileName().compareTo(pivot.getFileName()) < 0){
>             lesser.add(list.get(i));
>         }
>     }
>     ...
> ```

It should be

> ```
>     ...
>     else if (list.get(i).getExtention().compareTo(pivot.getExtention()) == 0){
>         if (list.get(i).getFileName().compareTo(pivot.getFileName()) < 0){
>             lesser.add(list.get(i));
>         } else {
>               greater.add(list.get(i));
>         }
>     }
>     ...
> ```

Also note that since you choose the first item as pivot, you should start the loop at 1 and not zero (in order not to insert the pivot twice)

Comment: right! that was the problem!! thank you! (and yes, it is for educational purposes)

Comment: If the answer helped you and you think it's correct you can upvote it